# Customized Force Fields - Modifying collosion options?

Tags: python, physics, rigid-body-simulation, force-fields

I am new to ***force fields*** in Blender. I was wondering if it is possible to define a new customized force field for rigid body simulations by scripting?

Comment: There is some flexibility in existing force fields. How do you want a force field to behave.

Comment: I have randomly falling objects that can interact with each other before settling down. coefficient of restitution and Young's modulus are very important in this simulation. So I need to define them, since I could not find them in blender options.

Comment: I also want to implement Hertz-Mindlin Contact model, to model the contacts between the particles.